# Async function does not work with Await

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following set up where my `main()` function makes an AJAX call and calls `getValue1()` and `getValue2()` inside SUCCESS. I am learning how to use the keywords **async** and **await**

According to this [SO post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and this developer [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success), the following code should work. However, it doesn't. Can someone tell me why?

```
async function main() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "...", 
      success: function (object) {
          var html = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
              var value1 = await getValue1(object[i].value1);
              html += '<p>' + value1 + '</p>';

              var value2 = await getValue2(object[i].value2);
              html += '<p>' + value2 + '</p>';

              console.log(html);
          }
      }
  });
}

function getValue1(value1) {
  $.ajax({
      url: "...", 
      success: function (value1) {
          return value1;
      } 
  });
}

function getValue2(value2) {
  $.ajax({
      url: "...", 
      success: function (value2) {
          return value2;
      } 
  });
}
```

Comment: As far as I know you need to return a Promise in order for async/await to function properly. This code doesn't do that.

Comment: ^^^ stick a return in front of $.ajax in your getValue methods.

Comment: @Taplar can you please add an answer with your method

Comment: @tadman can you please add an answer with your method

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Not to say you have to mark function with `async` keyword to use await inside. I mean the one you are passing as a success callback.

Comment: BTW your attempt to use `async/await` with (deprecated? or at least not recommended) `success` callback looks strange.

Comment: @tadman I am using JQuery 2.2.4

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to put the `async` keyword in the same function where `await` is. And for this to work, you need to return `Promise` in your `getValue1/2` functions.

The following code should work as it is, but note that:

1. all requests are processed simultaneously using `Promise.all`, so when they are all resolved it will log the result in console
2. I used `let` and `const` keywords, as I assumed that you use a recent version of JavaScript

You may need to take a look at the [Promise's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to fully understand the code below.

```
function main() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.ipify.org',
    success: function (object) {
      // this is for demonstration only:
      object = [
        {
          value1: 'https://api.ipify.org',
          value2: 'https://api.ipify.org',
        },
        {
          value1: 'https://api.ipify.org',
          value2: 'https://api.ipify.org',
        },
      ];
      // ^^^ remove this for your use

      // for some reasons, async callback in success won't work with jQuery
      // but using this self-calling async function will do the job
      (async function () {
        const requests = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
          requests.push(getValue1(object[i].value1));
          requests.push(getValue2(object[i].value2));
        }

        // all requests are done simultaneously
        const results = await Promise.all(requests);

        // will print ["<your ip>", "<your ip>", ...]
        console.log(results);
      })();
    },
  });
}

function getValue1(param1) {
  // return a promise that resolve when request is done
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      url: param1,
      success: resolve,
      error: reject,
    });
  });
}

function getValue2(param2) {
  // return a promise that resolve when request is done
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      url: param2,
      success: resolve,
      error: reject,
    });
  });
}

// call main for testing
main();
```

Comment: Why do you have two sets of values in objects[]?

Comment: As stated in the comments, this is for demonstration only. You can actually copy/paste this code to test it directly, but remove the "object = [...]" part for your own use.